# How to mention someone in a Wikipedia/Mediawiki conversation?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

In Wikipedia talk pages discussions, I see people often mention each other.
Mentioned people receive a notification.

How to mention people?

For instance let's say I want to mention the user called Joe.
Solutions that work on all Mediawiki sites preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Wikimedia "[pipe trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Pipe_trick)" to keep from having to repeat the username:

```
[[User:Username|]]
```

turns into

```
 [[User:Username|Username]]
```

---

Wikipedia<sup>1</sup> has some templates that are set up for this. You could just use the [User link template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:User_link)

```
{{u|Username}}
```

To be more "Twitter-like", there's the [ping template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Reply_to) (aka "Reply to")

> This template is particularly helpful in discussions that are not threaded, to indicate which user's comment is referenced.

```
{{ping|Username}}
```

results in

```
@[[User:Username|Username]]
```

More information at [Wikipedia:Notifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Notifications)

---

<sup>1</sup> English Wikipedia. Other language versions likely have different templates (if they have any).

Comment: The last link says: "Note that the post containing a link to a user page must be signed; if the edit does not add a new signature to the page, no notification will be sent." And to sign you add four tildes like this: ~~~~

Comment: On English Wikipedia, you mean :)

Comment: @tgr: You're right. I've updated my answer to specify.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in wikicode:

```
[[User:Joe|Joe]]
```

Example:

```
I agree with [[User:Joe|Joe]] above except the part about spiders.
```

Result:

[image]

If anyone knows an easier solution (especially one where I would not have to type the user name twice), I would love to hear about it.